# File upload issue in phonegap with ssl

Tags: android, file-upload, ssl, cordova

We have image upload functionality in our app. This functionality works fine when we use HTTP but fails when SSL is enabled. After some online surfing I got some code i.e to add true attribute in upload method

```
ft.upload(fileuri, encodeURI(PublishUrl+"FileUpload"), win, fail, options,true);
```

but it didn't worked

Error Log

```
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):    {"target":"Url","source":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/PopImg\/cache\/Car\/Crazy_Racer\/sm_1_(10).jpg","http_status":0,"code":3}
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526): java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.checkOpen(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:232)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:245)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:344)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526):            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-11 19:44:40.651: E/FileTransfer(17526): Failed after uploading 0 of 18171 bytes.
```

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: I am also facing the exact same problem and same error log. Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: Tried with changing fiddler configuration. In fiddler option, unchecked 'Capture HTTPS CONNECTs' option. Its working fine now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing purpose my mobile traffic was routed through Fiddler.Android devices may not work with the default HTTPS interception certificates used by Fiddler. By disabling fiddler it worked.